# Ironpython string replace on 16-bit unicode character

Tags: unicode, ironpython

In 2.6.4, is there a reason I can't do:

```
"my string".replace(u'\u200E', '')
```

without getting an index exception?  This looks like a bug in IronPython but I'm not sure...

Comment: If that's true, I'd say it's a bug too.

Comment: Works on 2.6.4 from macports, could be IronPython only.

Comment: Definitely looks like an IronPython bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug and I have filed a patch for it.

Answer (score 0):

try this: "my string".replace(u'\\u200E', '')